How to get the first mint transaction by token address using a request?
is there any request in the API Helius to get the first transaction/mint transaction for a token? I would like to extract the dev address from the token address, but via getasset it is often extracted incorrectly (creator is an empty field, and the authority is replaced) and it is best to do this via mint transaction, but parsing all transactions takes a long time.
Maybe you can recommend another API or another way to extract?

I'd suggest using the getSignaturesForAddress RPC call for the mint address to just get the transaction signatures. This returns just the transaction signatures involving the account, newest first. This is paginated (limit 1000) but just returns signatures so should be much faster than parsing the transactions. Once you have the signature of the earliest transaction you can use the Helius API to parse that one (or just view it in an Explorer) and see what you need.
